# Javascript random image not working in IE, adding a border in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, border, image-rotation

I am very new at coding, so please bear with me. I am more than willing to answer any questions or clarify any point in which I am unclear. I have this code which is displaying BEAUTIFULLY in firefox, but it adds a border around my image div in IE and Chrome. I have tried to override the user agent stylesheet (which is apparently where the border is coming from when I inspect the page with firebug) but nothing I do is changing the border displaying in IE and chrome. Has anyone else had this issue? I am finding some posts relating to it, but inevitably the poster responds "I figured it out" and then doesn't post their solution!

I also have a div at the bottom of the site that is rotating images on page refresh, through a list of images.  In IE, instead of a new image showing each time you refresh the page, the page is displaying a static image (number 3 in my image list). I have scoured the internet for some sort of reason that this wouldn't be working in IE, but I can't seem to find any code that is more compatible with IE than the javascript I am using currently.  The static image issue is the important one, as I have another javascript element on the site that is also not displaying in IE, from the same source, so I figure if someone helps me fix the first one, I can fix the second one on my own.

```
<script language="javascript">
function banner() { } ; b = new banner() ; n = 0
b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter1'>"
b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter2'>"
b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter3'>"
b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter4'>"
b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter5'>"
b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter6'>"
b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter7'>"
b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter8'>"
b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter9'>"
b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter10'>"
i=Math.floor(Math.random() * n) ; 
document.write( b[i] ) 
</script>
```

The css for one of the elements is below (in case that is somehow adding the border or preventing the images from displaying in IE...?)

```
    img.aligncenter1 { 
background: url(images/bottom01.png) no-repeat; 
width:662px;
height:395px;
display: block;
border:none; 
clear: both;
z-index:100;
margin-top:-35px;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Please let me know if I haven't posted enough code here.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is written into an `a` element, you can get rid of the border by setting `outline: none;` for the image. But, I've no clue what do you mean with "static instead of rotation", there's nothing referring to some "rotate" in your snippets.

Comment: The top chunk of code is causing my images to rotate on page refresh (not rotate angle wise but rotate to the next image in the set. The images aren't written into a elements, unfortunately.

Comment: No I understand the "rotating" : ). Perhaps it's due to the random source you set for them...

Comment: Ok, I posted this somewhere else, and got a response with new code that fixed the border issue:

    `<script language="javascript">
    i= Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 9);
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i
    }
    document.write('<img src="http://eventswithvizability.ca/wp-content/themes/lugada/images/bottom' + i + '.png" class="random_image" id="random_image_' + i + '" alt="" />')
</script>`

That resolved the border issue! It was a bug with transparent .pngs and using css to resize my images.

Comment: However, with this new code absolutely nothing is displaying in IE now where the images should be rotating.